# Как менять текст ссылки по клику?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть кнопка

```
<a href="" onClick='this.innerHTML="Скрыть"' >Ещё</a>
```

Изначально название гиперссылки "Ещё", после нажатия оно становится "Скрыть" и остаётся в этом же состоянии при дальнейших нажатиях. Как сделать, что при каждом нажатии название ссылки менялось циклично?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<a href="#" onClick='this.innerHTML=="Ещё" ? this.innerHTML="Скрыть" : this.innerHTML="Ещё"'>Ещё</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

html:

```
  <a href="" onClick='handler()'>Ещё</a>
```

js:

```
function handler(e){
  var el = e.target;
  if(el.innerHTML == "Скрыть"){
    el.innerHTML = "Еще";
  } else {
    el.innerHTML = "Скрыть";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая строка HTML - подключение JQery.

```js
$('#changeA').click(function(){
  if($('#changeA').hasClass('firstText')){
    $('#changeA').text('Скрыть');
    $('#changeA').removeClass('firstText');
    $('#changeA').addClass('secondText');
  }else{
    $('#changeA').text('Ещё');
    $('#changeA').removeClass('secondText');
    $('#changeA').addClass('firstText');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="changeA" class="firstText">Ещё</a>
```